# maxdepth switch ignored by find running in crontab

Tags: 16.04, cron, find

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS VMWare Cloud Server

The -maxdepth switch of the find command is ignored when used within the root crontab.  When the exact same command is run from the command line the maxdepth switch is observed by the find command and is effective.

This command archives only the contents of the directory /var/www/news without recursion into subdirectories (Desired behavior):

```
$ (cd /; find var/www/news -maxdepth 1 -print0) | /bin/tar -C / --null -T - -zcvf /mnt/nfs/Backup-Static-Sites/backupfile.tar.gz
```

This root crontab command archives the contents of all contents under directory /var/www/news ( totally ignoring the -maxdepth 1 switch / undesired behavior)

```
10 0 * * * (cd /; find var/www/news -maxdepth 1 -print0) | /bin/tar -C / --null -T - -zcvf /mnt/nfs/Backup-Static-Sites/backupfile.tar.gz
```

Is there a way to activate the observance of the maxdepth switch when the find command is executed from within the root crontab ?

Comment: Are you sure the first case works as you describe? I suspect what you are seeing has nothing to do with the find command's `-maxdepth` - rather, it's because you are passing the names of *directories* to `tar` - which is then recursively archiving them.

Comment: You are correct. The CLI version does the same thing as the crontab version.  I ran the find command by itself and the CLI echod the correct elements for archiving. Tar is supposed to be receiving piped output from the find command for source elements to archive.   How does the command need to be changed to achieve the desired result ?

Comment: Do you want just *files* at the top level - or files *and empty directories*?

Comment: Just files at the top level. A subdirectory name without the content of the subdirectory is  okay.  The subdirectories house timestamped, news page  snapshots that don't need to be backed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with directory exclusion to stop recursion using tar only, eliminating the use of find.

```
14 8 * * * /bin/tar -C / -zcvf /mnt/nfs/Backup-Static-Sites/html-News-Snapshot.tar.gz var/www/html-news.domain.tld --exclude "var/www/html-news.domain.tld/dir1"   . . "var/www/html-news.domain.tld/dirN"
```

Other techniques mentioned in this thread didn't work, ie. --no-recursion and -type F ! -type d

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is not anything to do with `-maxdepth`, it's because the list of files from your `find` command includes top-level directories, which are then recursively archived by `tar`.

Current versions of GNU `tar` have a `--no-recursion` option to turn off recursive directory traversal. However if you don't wish to archive the empty top-level directories, probably the simplest solution is to omit directories from the listing by adding `-type f` or `! -type d` to the `find` command:

```
10 0 * * * (cd /; find var/www/news -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -print0) | /bin/tar -C / --null -T - -zcvf /mnt/nfs/Backup-Static-Sites/backupfile.tar.gz
```

Comment: I found --no-recursion option of GNU tar did not work, and the server does use GNU tar. Hopefully one day this no-recursion feature will be fixed.  Couldn't get the other techniques mentioned, ie -type F ! -type d.